# Getting an error in Winforms: "The name type 'ASCIIEncodingSealed' does not exist in the type 'ASCIIEncoding'" // VS 2019

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my first time using `winforms` and I also have limited experience with C#. I've dealt with a few issues I had already but I'm getting this error message for the below form.designer.cs code: "The name type `ASCIIEncodingSealed` does not exist in the *type* `ASCIIEncoding`"

I'm trying to send a string across a *serial port* to an **Arduino** if that helps. I looked up a few solutions but not much relevant comes up when I search the error code.

I have put space and arrows around the line that the error is referring to in the below code:

```cs
namespace testProject
{
    using System.Text;
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();

//vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCIIEncodingSealed asciiEncodingSealed3 = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCIIEncoding();
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

            System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback decoderReplacementFallback3 = new System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback();
            System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback encoderReplacementFallback3 = new System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback();
            this.port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // port
            // 
            this.port.BaudRate = 9600;
            this.port.DataBits = 8;
            this.port.DiscardNull = false;
            this.port.DtrEnable = false;
            asciiEncodingSealed3.DecoderFallback = decoderReplacementFallback3;
            asciiEncodingSealed3.EncoderFallback = encoderReplacementFallback3;
            this.port.Encoding = asciiEncodingSealed3;
            this.port.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
            this.port.NewLine = "\n";
            this.port.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
            this.port.ParityReplace = ((byte)(63));
            this.port.PortName = "COM6";
            this.port.ReadBufferSize = 4096;
            this.port.ReadTimeout = -1;
            this.port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
            this.port.RtsEnable = false;
            this.port.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
            this.port.WriteBufferSize = 2048;
            this.port.WriteTimeout = -1;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(484, 461);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseMove);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
        private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort port;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect there to be an `ASCIIEncodingSealed`?

Comment: What is `ASCIIEncodingSealed`? There [is no](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=ASCIIEncodingSealed%20) such framework type. From where comes this type? Can you link a tutorial (site) you are using?

Comment: @Sintar I did not write most of this portion of the code. It was automatically created when I was designing the form (I assume). I'm not sure why this part of the code is there but I assume it's there for something to do with sending ASCII values over the serial port

Comment: @Llama See my comment above. I'm not even exactly sure what that line is meant to be doing. While I have some coding experience in a few languages, C#, winforms and transmitting data over ports is all pretty new to me

Comment: To save or transfer text, you have to be able to represent it as bytes rather than as characters. There are different standards which define how this text<->conversion should take place, of which ASCII is one of them. I'm afraid that I'm not sure what `ASCIIEncodingSealed` is as it isn't part of .NET. Perhaps you could just change it to `ASCII` and see if that works?

Comment: `ASCIIEncodingSealed` does exist - it's just an internal implementation detail: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Text/ASCIIEncoding.cs#L31. My guess is that there's a bug in the designer and it's generating incorrect code that won't compile.

Comment: @Martin That's the conclusion I've come to after searching for this on GitHub.

Comment: @Llama thanks for that. I tried changing it to "ASCII" but that spit out errors too. then I tried "ASCIIEncoding" and it got rid of those errors but now theres an error on 2 other lines, one of them being: "asciiEncodingSealed3.DecoderFallback = decoderReplacementFallback3;"

Comment: @Martin I think you're probably right. I did install a package (or tool) for serial ports for this project that was supposed to be preinstalled but I couldn't access it under the tools menu for some reason. That package I installed may be the problem. I'm not sure how I would Go about fixing it. Would downloading a different version of VS help? I have the latest preview of VS 2019 at the moment. Apparently the version I have does not support the serial port tool out of the box